# Could not deduce (m ~ m1)

Tags: haskell

When compiling this program in GHC:

```
import Control.Monad

f x = let
  g y = let
    h z = liftM not x
    in h 0
  in g 0
```

I receive an error:

```
test.hs:5:21:
    Could not deduce (m ~ m1)
    from the context (Monad m)
      bound by the inferred type of f :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool
      at test.hs:(3,1)-(7,8)
    or from (m Bool ~ m1 Bool, Monad m1)
      bound by the inferred type of
               h :: (m Bool ~ m1 Bool, Monad m1) => t1 -> m1 Bool
      at test.hs:5:5-21
      `m' is a rigid type variable bound by
          the inferred type of f :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool
          at test.hs:3:1
      `m1' is a rigid type variable bound by
           the inferred type of
           h :: (m Bool ~ m1 Bool, Monad m1) => t1 -> m1 Bool
           at test.hs:5:5
    Expected type: m1 Bool
      Actual type: m Bool
    In the second argument of `liftM', namely `x'
    In the expression: liftM not x
    In an equation for `h': h z = liftM not x
```

Why? Also, providing an explicit type signature for `f` (`f :: Monad m => m Bool -> m Bool`) makes the error disappear. But this is exactly the same type as the type that Haskell infers for `f` automatically, according to the error message!

Comment: Monomorphism restriction?

Comment: Monomorphism restriction only applies to simple pattern bindings, and there are none here. Anyway, adding `-XNoMonomorphismRestriction` has no effect.

Comment: I would think it's related to let-generalization, since the error disappears with `-XMonoLocalBinds`

Answer (score 5):

This is pretty straightforward, actually. The inferred types of `let`-bound variables are implicitly generalised to type schemes, so there’s a quantifier in your way. The generalised type of `h` is:

```
h :: forall a m. (Monad m) => a -> m Bool
```

And the generalised type of `f` is:

```
f :: forall m. (Monad m) => m Bool -> m Bool
```

They’re not the same `m`. You would get essentially the same error if you wrote this:

```
f :: (Monad m) => m Bool -> m Bool
f x = let
  g y = let
    h :: (Monad m) => a -> m Bool
    h z = liftM not x
    in h 0
  in g 0
```

And you could fix it by enabling the “scoped type variables” extension:

```
{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}

f :: forall m. (Monad m) => m Bool -> m Bool
f x = let
  g y = let
    h :: a -> m Bool
    h z = liftM not x
    in h 0
  in g 0
```

Or by disabling `let`-generalisation with the “monomorphic local bindings” extension, `MonoLocalBinds`.

Comment: It's not that straightforward, since with `ghc <= 7.6.1`, the problem doesn't arise, even with explicit `NoMonoLocalBinds`. The behaviour changed with 7.6.2, I don't know whether intentionally, or accidentally.

Comment: Why doesn't this happen to `f x = let g y = liftM not x in g 0`? The type of `g` should be generalized in the same way.

Comment: Maybe it is a bug then. In which case the question and answer are a good repro case and place to start looking.